# Codeigniter with PHPspreadsheet how to put a condition if a data in database is empty the cell column will turn into red

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

Hi good day everyone who had an idea on how to make my PO status column cell will be red if there is no data yet had been inserted to the database. I am using phpspreadsheet in code igniter framework.

This is my spreadsheet code witch I want it if there is no PO STATUS yet the color will be seen in my column status is red.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Control Number');
        $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Requesting Unit');
        $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Project Details');
        $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'PO STATUS');
```

this is $data is the model where the sql query will fetch and how i fetch my data into the database.

```
 $data = $this->m->statuswaived();
            $slno = 1;
            $start = 2;
            foreach($data as $d){
                $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$start, $d->control_number);
                $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$start, $d->requesting_unit);
                $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$start, $d->project_details);
                $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$start, $d->po_status);
                
                
            $start = $start+1;
            $slno = $slno+1;
            }
```

this code is for putting the border in my excel

```
$styleThinBlackBorderOutline = [
                    'borders' => [
                        'allBorders' => [
                            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => ['argb' => 'FF000000'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
```

this code is use for bolding a cell column and alignment and fontsize that i set.

```
//Font BOLD
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setBold(true);        
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->applyFromArray($styleThinBlackBorderOutline);
    //Alignment
    //fONT SIZE
    // $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setSize(12);

    $sheet->getStyle('A1:D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

This code is for setting the with of the cell column.

```
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(30);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(30);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(30);
```